# Mouse click (both left and right) deselects/unfocus window

Tags: windows-10, drivers, mouse, mouse-click

I'm using an *HP Pavilion laptop (model 15-cc1xx)*. It has a touchpad but I also use a USB mouse.

Recently, the click commands from my mouse doesn't seen to work. Rather the windows get deselected whenever I click on them. Same thing happens with the touchpad. Even when I tried the touchpad without the USB mouse plugged in. The mouse movement, however, works correctly.

I tried uninstalling and the reinstalling the drivers of the both devices but that doesn't seem to fix the problem. However, if I let my device sleep and then wake up, or shutdown and turn on again, or restart the device, the problem seems to be gone for a while. But it returns a few minutes later.

I had an **HP Inc - HIDClass driver update (version 2.1.14.1)** before the problem occurred. Does this update has something to do with the problem? Where can I uninstall the driver from?

**Update:** I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the drivers under **Human Interface Device** but that didn't seem to help.

Comment: That is a USB Bus Driver and seems to be the latest driver. Ask HP for an update. Also try a different (maybe newer) USB mouse

Comment: Is there any option for rollback? Does switching to a new mouse would help (I doubt 'cause the touchpad on the laptop also has the same problem)?

Comment: I did not see a way to roll back. You may need to ask HP Support

Comment: I rolled back to version 2.1.13.1. Now the problem is fixed. Thanks for taking your time to help me.